# How can I prevent battery saver from disabling when the device is charging?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, battery, charging, 5.1-lollipop

The battery saver functionality in Android 5.0 and 5.1 automatically turns itself off when the device is "charging". Unfortunately, when I'm charging my tablet from my car, most of the time the charge is insufficient to counter the drain on the battery so I would like battery saver to remain on even when charging.

Is this possible and if so, how can I achieve this?